# Child Processes errors in apache logs

Tags: apache-2.2

```
    Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17193 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17194 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17195 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17196 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17197 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17198 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17199 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17200 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17201 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17212 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17213 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:50 2012] [error] child process 17214 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 16995 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 16996 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 16998 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17000 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17001 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17012 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17013 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17014 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17015 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17016 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17019 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17020 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17024 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17025 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17027 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17029 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17030 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17032 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17035 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17037 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17038 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17040 exit, attempting to continue anyway
[Wed Feb 22 23:54:51 2012] [error] could not make child process 17041 exit, attempting to continue anyway
```

Any idea on what this means ??

Comment: Do any of these [existing questions](http://serverfault.com/search?q=%22could+not+make+child+process%22+%22exit%2C+attempting+to+continue+anyway%22) match your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problematic apache restart.